# Is kapt supported in bazel?

Tags: android, kotlin, bazel, kapt

In **gradle** I use Realm and Dagger library. These library require using kapt annotation for generate their classes.

How I can in **Bazel** use this annotations?

Comment: Are you writing Kotlin code, and want to use Realm/Dagger in that code, or are you writing Java code and the Realm/Dagger annotations depend on Kotlin / kapt? If you're writing Kotlin code, are you using https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin or something else?

Comment: (I'm guessing that this is your question here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/issues/144)

Comment: Realm uses the Gradle Transform API so i honestly wonder if Realm can be configured to run with that.